# Split string into Elements of Array

Tags: java, arrays

Simple question:

If I have an input of two numbers:

```
readMessage = "2 3";
String[] result = readMessage.split("\\s");
```

How would I call each of those parts separately in the array?

Would result[0] = 2 and result[1] = 3? Is this correct?

Comment: You can use System.out.print to test your prediction

Comment: Certainly you tried this before you asked. What was the result when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right on this. Here are few example accessing array:

Printing using array index:

```
System.out.println(result[0]);
System.out.println(result[1]);
```

But better and safe practice to check the length first to avoid Exception:

```
if(result.length >= 2){
    System.out.println(result[1]);
}
```

Using a for each loop:

```
for(String r: result){
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Using a regular loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    System.out.println(result[i]);
}
```

Testing your array using Arrays class

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String list[]=str.split(" ");
```

will work